# Active Admin and has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to get my user model to work in ActiveAdmin but it seems to only work when I refer the models back to the user model itself, which then breaks my forms in my app.

This way breaks my ActiveAdmin user view but by forms work in my app.

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :vehicle
  has_one :permit
  has_one :faculty
  has_one :emergency_contact
  has_one :student

  def admin?
    roles == "admin"
  end

  def editor?
    roles == "editor"
  end

  def standard?
    roles == "standard"
  end

end
```

user.rb

```
has_many :vehicle, class_name: 'User'
has_one :permit, class_name: 'User'
has_one :faculty, class_name: 'User'
has_one :emergency_contact, class_name: 'User'
has_one :student, class_name: 'User'
```

The second way is what gets my ActiveAdmin user view to work (I know this is wrong just don't know how to fix it) but it breaks my forms in my app. When ActiveAdmin is broken I am getting the error:
`undefined method 'vehicle_id_eq' for Ransack::Search<class: User` when I click on the users view in ActiveAdmin.

Anyone have any ideas on what I can do to fix my model to get ActiveAdmin to work properly?

Edit**

admin/user.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
    permit_params :roles
end
```

models/vehicle.rb

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to  :user
end
```

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace of the error? and the exact request too?

Comment: Also add the admin view you've created for the User model if you can.

Comment: So the full trace is super long and about 50 lines of redirects. Do you still want all of it? The request is all I'm doing is calling upon the page /admin/users

Comment: Fair, how about the top 10 lines? I'm mostly interested in the ActiveAdmin part of the stack trace. Or you can put the whole thing in a paste bin and just link it here.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JZvpS5rS
Forgot about pastebin.

Comment: Thanks. I can already tell you that this is a strange error coming from AA. It's doing a Ransacker search on the User model with the predicate `vehicle_id_eq` like it's a `belongs_to` association filter.

Comment: Well I didn't add any of the other models. But the vehicle.rb model does have a `belongs_to :user`. Is that where I am having my issue?

Comment: No that's fine. If a User `has_many` Vehicles, then it makes sense that a Vehicle `belongs_to` a User.

Comment: So is this not a common error in AA and is just breaking my app? I'm just not sure why it has to be associated with and have the `class_name :user` in it.

Comment: It doesn't. The `class_name` keyword is used to tell Rails which class should be used as the Model if the association's name isn't like the model name. It's intended to work like this `has_many :cars, -> { where(make_type: "Car") }, class_name: "Vehicle"`. Like I said, that's a Rails thing, not an AA thing. However, AA does make a set of default filters (that form that seems to be breaking), and *it* should know that it can't search the User model for a `vehicle_id` based on the association type (aka `has_many`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveAdmin is trying to create filters for all your associations on the User model. That appears to include your `has_many` association (and `has_one`s too I'd guess). This is such a simple case that it seems buggy that AA is trying to create filters for `has_one` or `has_many` associations by default. It might be worth [reporting on Github](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues). In the mean time, there are a few ways to get around this issue.

1. Specify your own filters

in `admin/user.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
    permit_params :roles

    filter :name
    filter :email
    # or you can remove filters with => remove_filter :vehicles
    #... add more filters that as you need.
end
```

This way you have the filters you'd actually use to find a single or set of users.

2. You can `join` or `include` the models that are on being referenced. I'd only recommend this **if you actually plan on filtering Users by any of those associations**. If not, use the first method mentioned above.

in `admin/user.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
    permit_params :roles

    controller do
      active_admin_config.includes.push :vehicles, :permit #,... etc.

      # IF YOU INCLUDE A `has_many`, you need to ensure you are not 
      # returning duplicate resources. So you need to overwrite
      # the apply_filtering method
      def apply_filtering(collection)
        super.where(User.primary_key => collection)
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: I am not fully sure why but me adding the `filter :email` did the job. It seems if I add a filter of anything it fixes the AA. However I'm not sure if adding the filter is supposed to change anything on the user view, but it does not.

Comment: When you don't specify any filters manually, AA will create a set of "default" filters based on the Model. In this case it was adding filters that were bad (the has many and has one filters weren't searchable with Ransack). Once you add even one filter, AA won't add *any* of the default filters. That is why it seemed to suddenly work when you added the email filter. It sounds like a bug to me tho. AA shouldn't try to add filters for associations that can't be searched on the Model. Still glad I could help!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It makes sense now and why AA might be doing this.

Comment: I agree a GitHub issue seems justified here.  @wspurgin?

Comment: Sounds good. @PiersC, I'll make one now. Wanted to give the OP a chance to make one if they desired.

Comment: Added this [issue](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/5236). @BryceRenninger, I can't reproduce the error you were having. If you have your code on Github (or some publicly accessible place), can you link it on that issue?

Comment: Sure, its currently all under my testing branch.

https://github.com/brenninger01/csc4500_permits.git